# Alignment with NN translator

Tags: microsoft-translator

I use TranslateArray2 to get alignment information. Is there a way to get the aligments back when using category=generalnn? I only get them with the default category (and the older models).

Comment: Did you ever get more info on this?

Comment: no, no response unfortunately.